# how to detect transparent area in our png image with java, android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to detect transparent area of the image and want to merge second image with that transparent area of first image..... with java part in android..

i have done coding of merge image but it is not merging on transparent area of first image....

```
     public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
    Bitmap cs = null;

    int width, height = 0;

    if (c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) {
        width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    } else {
        width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    }

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, 0f, null);

    return cs;
  }
```

Comment: try to get rgba values from your bitmap, if it's transparent possibly its alpha will be 0

Comment: Ounr A. is right, well you need to define a threshold value < based on RRGGBBB > ,check for all the pixel from (o,o) to (height ,width)and any pixel containing the value of rrggbb less than that threshold is a transparent part of the image , you can just keep a track of all those pixel in an array ,

Comment: @amit have you got solution for this? i check this https://github.com/ketanpatel25/Image-Cropping-In-Transparent-Area but it not work as requirement it just set as background image

Comment: hi...did you find any solution? i have same issue